# how to append nothing (not None) in list comprehension?

Tags: python

I want to append a string to a list if certain condition happens

```
some_result = some_check # some_result would have either an empty dict or some content
tag = ['a_tag' if some_result else None]
```

This would actually append a `None` to the list, but I want it to append nothing instead. Also tried empty string, empty dict, etc. Doesn't seem like it's working either

EDIT: didn't realize this is not a list comprehension. Thanks for clearing it.

Comment: What list comprehension?

Comment: `'a_tag' if some_result else None` that's a ternary expression not list comp. You have to actually _iterate_ on something.

Comment: You could use `.extend` like so. `your_list.extend(['a_tag'] if condition else [])`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is not list comprehension. It's the [terniary operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) inside a list (similar to say, `tag = ['something',]`, whereas list comprehension has a `for` keyword inside ([ref](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)).

An `if` statement would be the cleanest way to deal with this logic IMO:

```
tag = []
if some_result:
    tag.append('a_tag')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you had was actually very close to working.

```
tags = ["t1", "t2"]
some_result = some_check()
tags.append("a_tag") if some_result else None
```

This appends to `tags` if `some_result` is truthy, otherwise leaves it untouched.